# Upper and lower bounding the modified Bessel function of the first kind and zeroth order

Tags: bessel-functions

Some moths ago I stumbled upon the following upper and lower bound on the modified Bessel function of the first kind and zeroth order:

$\frac{e^{x}}{1 + 2x} < I_0(x) < \frac{e^{x}}{\sqrt{1 + 2x}}, x > 0$.

Now I have trouble finding the reference, is there any way of finding this or proving these bounds? Are they even true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found paper I was looking for!

*Yang, Zhen-Hang; Chu, Yu-Ming*, [**On approximating the modified Bessel function of the first kind and Toader-Qi mean**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1186/s13660-016-0988-1), J. Inequal. Appl. 2016, Paper No. 40, 21 p. (2016). [ZBL1332.33009](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1332.33009).https://link.springer.com/article/10.1186/s13660-016-0988-1

The double inequality I was looking for (and proof) can be found in Theorem 3.1.

Answer (score 0):

FYI this lower bound can be easily improved to gain a factor of $\sqrt{x}$ to become only a constant factor from the correct $x\to\infty$ asymptotics. See [Lower bounds on the modified Bessel function of the first kind](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3854698/lower-bounds-on-the-modified-bessel-function-of-the-first-kind/4056995#4056995)